# Convert value/pair list (simple array) into JSON with properties using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a simple value pair array like this :

```
array(4) (
  [4] => (string) Barcelona
  [3] => (string) Cordoba
  [1] => (string) Granada
  [2] => (string) Jaen
)
```

I need to encode this to JSON to respond to an AJAX request in the following format :

```
[{"pk": 4, "name": "Barcelona"},
{"pk": 3, "name": "Cordoba"},
{"pk": 1, "name": "Granada"},
{"pk": 2, "name": "Jaen"}]
```

If I use :

```
json_encode($a)
```

I get the following :

```
{"4":"Barcelona","3":"Cordoba","1":"Granada","2":"Jaen","0":"Select a province"}
```

How do I get PHP to format my simple array to include properties in the JSON?

Comment: Have you tried iterating yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a new array:

```
$data = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array('pk' => $key, 'name' => $value);
}

$json = json_encode($data);
```